# When executing LOAD DATA in Hive, does it copies the data?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hdfstore

When loading data stored in HDFS into HIVE, does this data from HDFS gets copied into a different format used by HIVE? Or does it uses the original files to store/select/insert/modify the data?

Context: 
LOAD DATA INPATH '/home/user/sample.txt' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE employee;

Does HIVE uses /home/user/sample.txt always to store/select/insert/modify the data, or does it creates a new file occupying new space at HDFS/HBASE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is explained in the [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-Loadingfilesintotables) :

> If the keyword LOCAL is not specified, then Hive will either use the full URI of filepath, if one is specified, or will apply the following rules:
>   [...]
>   **Hive will move the files addressed by filepath into the table (or partition)**

Answer (score 2):

`LOAD DATA INPATH` does nothing except moving the HDFS files into the location of the table, and by "moving" I mean a metadata operation of the HDFS.